# Count Child Objects, change field for each object after the first

Tags: workflow, fields, childrecords

Is it possible to count the number of child objects and specify a field to be "X" if it is the secondary, tertiary(etc) object tied to the parent, without using a trigger?

Comment: Is it `Lookup` or `Master-Detail` relationship? What do you mean by secondary and tertiary? Just order of `CreatedDate`?

Comment: It is a lookup relationship.  And yes, what I need is for the first child record of a parent record to have a field set to 'New Business' while any additional child records created for that same parent have the field set to 'Repeat Business'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the child records simply using a `Rollup Summary Field`. Salesforce documents this type of field extensively, see **[Roll-Up Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en)** and **[Defining Roll-Up Summaries](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US)**. Once you have the RSF, you can simply update your child record's field via `Workflow Field Update` using a formula like:

```
CASE(Parent__r.Child_Count__c,
    0, "Primary Value",
    1, "Secondary Value",
    "Tertiary Value"
)
```

Or if you only care whether or not it's the first child:

```
IF(Parent__r.Child_Count__c = 0, "New Business", "Repeat Business")
```

Make sure you add this field update to a `Workflow Rule` on the child object that you evaluate only when the record is created.